# Python printing with and without newline

Tags: python

How can I print all of the output on the same line? Something like ",,,key, value". The below creates a newline for every preceding ','.

```
for i in range(0, depth):
    print(',')
print("{}, {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: use the `end` flag within the `print` call?

Comment: @Ruturaj: The `flush=True` part isn't necessary if you expect to print a newline soon. You'd want to avoid it if you were printing without sleeps or blocking calls so as to avoid spending excessive time on per-print system calls for small outputs.